# Advice/Insight: How to safely update an Angular 4 app to Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, upgrade, azure-webapps, angular-upgrade

I'm about to go head first into doing a MAJOR versioning upgrade for a legacy Angular 4 app into an Angular 6 app. I figured I could push the envelope into version 6 at most without completeley bricking the app.

That said, I know I'm about to enter into some gotchas, so I'd like insight from seasoned JavaScript Developers who have already performed these game-breaking updates.

**First, I do know that these assumptions are true:**

- https://update.angular.io/#4.4:6.1l3
- I must be all in with the Angular CLI and how it operates. Everything from kickstarting your localhost, creating a new component, to building out the final web app.

**Next, here are some things to know about the existing web app:**

- Angular 4.4.7
- ES module loader is, SystemJS.
- Source code sits in Bitbucket with a direct connection into a Microsoft Azure Web App provision (NodeJS). Once the final artifact is built out via gulp task, it ships automatically into the cloud.
- This web app does NOT use the Angular CLI.

**Finally, here is my desired upgrade path for the aforementioned app:**

- Angular 6.1
- ES module loader will be, webpack.
- Source code will still sit in Bitbucket with a direct connection into a Microsoft Azure Web App provision (NodeJS). I'd like the final artifact to be built out via gulp task (or whatever modern day task runner applies) it ships automatically into the cloud.
- This web app does will leverage the Angular CLI.

Thanks in advance for your insight.

Comment: This is not trivial. A non-cli project can not easily be transformed to a cli-project, because I doubt the creator somehow made exactly the same decisions the cli does for you (most people start a new CLI-project and start copying and fixing, copying and fixing etc.

Comment: That suggestion in starting a new CLI project is very much valid IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look at here: https://update.angular.io/

Those steps listed in that link usually work.

The one thing I can say is: upgrade to version 5 and, afterward, to version 6. I've tried before to upgrade by jumping intermediary versions (from 6 to 9) and it was a terrible experience that took me like almost 2 hours in a small project.

Comment: But what about from the perspective of  a non-CLI project implementation to a CLI implementation? That's the broader hardship amongst other things.

Comment: Man... no shortcut. Start with the cli conversion. After that, do the angular update. If it's possible, just copy and paste the files of the non-cli project to a fresh cli project. I think it's the best you can do. :(